# jQuery Galleria slideshow, troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, slideshow, galleria, jquery-1.4

I am trying to install the jquery slideshow "galleria" found here: [Galleria site - How to install it (script)](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/getting_started/beginners_guide/)

I already call the jquery library in the "head" of my site like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>` for the slidetoogle effect.` Do I have to repost this line of code one more time for the "Galleria" slideshow or once is enough for these plugins and all future ones?

Here is the script I use for the "galleria" calling the jquery library for the second time but it is the 1.4.4 this time:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script><script src="http://xxx.com/file/xxx/galleria-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
```

In the body I put: `<div id="gallery">
            <img src="http://xxx/file/xxx/80.jpg">
            <img src="http://xxx/file/xxx/81.jpg">
            <img src="http://xxx/file/xxx/82.jpg">
        </div>
<script>
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            $("#gallery").galleria({
                width: 500,
                height: 500
            });
        </script>`

Nothing appears.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include jQuery once.

You can try adding this to the body:

```
<script>
if (Galleria) { $("body").text('Galleria works') }
</script>
```

if the message "Galleria works" doesn't show up, one of your paths is probably wrong. Make sure the path to "galleria-1.2.2.min.js" and "galleria.classic.min.js" is correct. Also make sure to use the newest version of jQuery and Galleria.

For a better answer, you need to post a link to the site.